# Can we have a "This is spam" radio in the Low Quality Posts queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, spam, low-quality-posts

I see a spammy post every now and then in the Low Quality Posts review queue, but there isn't a relevant comment I can leave the spammer. Therefore, I have to choose 'No comment Needed'. Can we have yet another choice?

**This post is spam**
*Flag this post as spam*

Currently I have to press the link button on the side, go the the post, mark it as spam, then go back to the queue and mark it for deletion. Quite a hassle, don't you think?

Comment: Presumably the spammer already knows they are spamming so don't need a comment telling them

Comment: @RichardTingle the idea is to flag the post, not to post an auto-comment

Comment: @JanDvorak As I understand it 6 recommend deletion flags auto deletes, as does 6 spam flags. An interesting question is does 3 recommend deletion flags + 3 spam flags autodelete; if it does then no change is nessissary. Any devs about to answer?

Comment: there is a difference or two: first, 6 spam flags carry a rep penalty. Second, spam flags never auto-clear, VLQ recommendations do.

Comment: @JanDvorak I've always found that slightly ridiculous; spammers don't care about rep, they always have 1 rep and they only ever post 1 post

Comment: They don't care about rep, but they do care about quality-ban, and they don't always post only one post per account.

Comment: @RichardTingle They are completely separate systems. It takes six spam flags *or* six deletion recommendations.

Comment: In that case it might make sense to be able to flag from the dialogue, but that argument would hold for any kind of flag/close vote as well as voting; wanting to downvote the things you see in the dialogue is probably more common than spam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the comments to leave on "recommend for deletion" reasons are for things a person could, with good intentions, have accidently done (not realising that answers were strictly for posts that answer the original question). As such informing them of their mistake is a good and useful thing to do.

However, no-one accidently posts spam, or cares that we don't like it. Therefore leaving such a comment would serve no purpose.

Being able to separately flag from the dialogue as spam may be helpful, but that argument would hold for any kind of flag, closing or voting.

Comment: the idea is to flag the post, not to post a comment

Comment: Possibly being able to additionally flag as spam within a the queue would useful, but that would still be 'No comment needed'

Comment: You are free to suggest a different UI. However, it feels safe to assume there is no desire to flag _and_ comment.

Comment: On one spam post, I have seen someone comment with "do not click on this" as an alert to others.  Some people may not be see the obvious spam (I've seen that happen in a separate incident).  It is important that each spam post is flagged by each person who finds it.

Comment: @Jamal I wouldn't object to the full post interaction being available in the queue